# how to strcat in OPENFILENAME paramaeters in C programming

Tags: c, strcat

I have a working code using OPENFILENAME. May i know how to use strcat to dynamically control the its parameters

this one is working

```
//ofn.lpstrFilter = "Rule Files (*.net and *.rul)\0*.rul;*.net\0";   

char filter[100];  
char filterText[100];  
char filterVal[100];
strcpy(filterText, "Rule Files (*.net and *.rul)");   
strcpy(filterVal, "*.rul;*.net");
```

I tried using strcat first with '\0' but it only only shows like this
`strcat (filter, filterText);`
`strcat (filter,"\0");`
`strcat (filter,filterVal);`
`strcat (filter,"\0");`
`ofn.lpstrFilter = filter; \\missing \0`

And I tried using '\\0'
`strcat (filter, filterText);`
`strcat (filter,"\\0");`
`strcat (filter,filterVal);`
`strcat (filter,"\\0");`

`ofn.lpstrFilter = filter; \\now includes the\0`

but when i run the program the dialogue box filter shows like this
 **"Rule Files (*.net and *.rul)\0*.rul;*.net\0";**

thanks

Comment: `strcat` concatenates strings ... are you wanting to concatenate or *split* a string, which actually requires `strtok`?

Comment: What you were doing earlier is correct. Why do you wish to show the terminating character ?

Comment: @Jason&Mahesh - i want to dynamically allow other user to set the filter text and filter values. So other user may just wish to use other option rather than a static type filter, other user may want their filter like this ofn.lpstrFilter = "All Files (\*.*)\0*.*\0";

Comment: @Jason&Mahesh - i edit and showed how i'm failing to combine filterText and filterVal with '\0' to correctly follow the correct syntax of ofn.lpstrFilter value. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `"\\0"` won't do anything useful, that will just put the literal two characters `\0` in your string when you want a nul byte. However, strings in C are terminated by `'\0'` so you can't use `strcat` to construct a nul delimited string without a bit of pointer arithmetic.

So, given these:

```
char filterText[] = "Rule Files (*.net and *.rul)";
char filterVal[]  = "*.rul;*.net";
char filter[100];
```

You'll need to do something like this:

```
/*
 * The first one is a straight copy.
 */
strcpy(filter, filterText);

/*
 * Here we need to offset into filter to right after the
 * nul byte from the first copy.
 */
strcpy(&filter[strlen(filterText) + 1], filterVal);
```

A better approach would be to allocate your `filter` with `malloc` so that you don't have to worry about buffer overflows:

```
char *filter = malloc(strlen(filterText) + 1 + strlen(filterVal) + 1);
```

Comment: @mu is too short - Thank you for the answer as well as for the malloc suggestion.

Comment: Or even: `size_t txt_len = strlen(filterText); size_t val_len = strlen(filterVal); char *filter = malloc(txt_len + val_len + 1); memmove(filter, filterText, txt_len); memmove(filter+txt_len, filterVal, val_len+1);`, optionally substituting `memcpy()` for `memmove()` because it is safe in this context, though `memmove()` is always safe and `memcpy()` is not always safe. (If the goal is to have two strings separated by a NUL in the result, then you need to adjust the length allocated by +1, the first length copied by +1, and the offset of the second copy by +1; or an equivalent set of changes).

Comment: @Jonathan: You could also use `sizeof(filterVal)` in place of `strlen(filterVal)+1` since `fitlerVal` is a `char[]`. That bizarre nul-delimited format is a Windows thing for (AFAIK) the standard file dialog so you do need the extra 1. Or just declare the whole thing as a single `char[]` as `{'R','u', ...}`.

Comment: Thanks for the info; I live, I learn, I forget.  You could just use: `char filter[] = "Rule Files (*.net and *.rul)\0*.rul;*.net";`, which succinctly gives you the result you require - unless there's an obnoxious compiler that thinks you can't possibly want the data after the first null in the string.

Comment: @Jonathan: Well, this is Windows... I figured a workable solution for a pair of arbitrary (but well formed) strings would be the best bet. You could even set the appropriate bits in an `int*` and cast it to a `char*`. Really depends on how much you hate the people that have to maintain your code. I'm still trying to forget my time doing Windows development and that was over a decade ago.

Comment: I'm still recovering from the scars of development on DOS (there wasn't Windows yet, AFAICR) nearly 30 years ago.